# Center buttons in dialog created with "gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons"

Tags: button, user-interface, dialog, gtk, alignment

I am writing a Gtk application and I am having troubles centering some buttons.
I created a popup window in this way:

```
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("Add element",
                                      GTK_WINDOW(gElems->window),
                                      GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT | GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                                      "OK",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                      "Cancel",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT,
                                      NULL);
```

Everything is ok, except for the OK and Cancel buttons, which are aligned to the right end of the popup window, while I would like them to be centered (as you can see from the picture).

[image]

Is there a way to do so without using additional containers to store the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align the buttons in the middle

```
    buttons_container = gtk_dialog_get_action_area (dialog)
    g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT (buttons_container), "halign", GTK_ALIGN_CENTER)
```

and voila.....

If you want to change the container, you also can, but that's not what you want, really

Answer (score 0):

Regarding luciomrx answer: It is needed to pass a gvalue, otherwise you will get a compile warning and a runtime crash:

```
GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init (&val, G_TYPE_ENUM);
g_value_set_enum (&val, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
buttons_container = gtk_dialog_get_action_area (dialog);
g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT (gtk_dialog_get_action_area (dialog)), "halign", &val);
```

Even Simpler, you can just use `gtk_widget_set_halign`, which accepts an enum:

```
gtk_widget_set_halign (gtk_dialog_get_action_area (dialog), GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Edit: I just realized that `gtk_dialog_get_action_area` anyhow is deprecated in gtk3 .. so a different sulution should be found.